# RobbieHanson's XMPPFramework didReceiveMessage not called

Tags: iphone, ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I'm developing on iOS and using Robbie Hanson XMPPFramework. The method didReceiveMessage is never called.

I did successfully connect, and sent 'presence' (confirmed by using NSLog. That can be confirmed by the Openfire admin panel which shows the user as green and connected.

```
    XMPPPresence* presence = [XMPPPresence presence]; // type="available" is implicit
[[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
```

Further, I received didReceiveIQ calls. I do not know what is IQ and do I need to handle it?

The most important thing is do I make didReceiveMessage get called. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you expecting didReceiveMessage calls? Are you sending this client messages? Sending a presence, I'd think, would probably generate an IQ response, not a message response. You ask, do I need to handle IQs - that all depends on what you're wanting to accomplish! Please edit your question to clarify those things.

Comment: First of all, what is IQ?

Comment: Read about the protocol! It'll help you understand the framework. http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3920.html#streams http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3920.html#stanzas http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3920.html#stanzas-semantics-iq

Comment: Can you show what have you written in `didReceiveMessage` method of `xmpp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The didReceiveMessage delegate will only be called if your client receives a message stanza like this:

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" from="juliet@capulet.net" to="romeo@capulet.net" id="21" type="chat"><body>This is a sample message.</body></message>
```

This stanza is received if other XMPP clients send you a chat message.  If your didReceiveIQ is already being called then we can assume that we have setup our delegates properly.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to have in mind is that after authentication you need to send a presence otherwise you won't receive any message.

Read the following blog post: [Build a complete iOS messaging app using XMPPFramework - Tutorial Part 1](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/blog/build-a-complete-ios-messaging-app-using-xmppframework-tutorial-part-1.html)

> After a sucessfull connection, you are not going to receive any `<message/>` until you make yourself available sending the previous presence. `<presence/>`

You should have something like this somewhere in your code:

```
func xmppStreamDidAuthenticate(_ sender: XMPPStream!) {
    self.xmppStream.send(XMPPPresence())
    print("Stream: Authenticated")
}
```

If you take a look to the second part of the tutorial I posted you will see how to perform the authentication and everything:

[Build a complete iOS messaging app using XMPPFramework - Part 2](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/blog/build-a-complete-ios-messaging-app-using-xmppframework-part-2.html)